# How do I install Flash in Opera?

Tags: apt, flash, 16.04, chromium, opera

I have problem with Adobe Flash Player. While using Opera, few of pages show me that I don't have flash installed. When I run this command in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`,

I get information that it's already installed. So I try to use this page https://get.adobe.com/pl/flashplayer/ to install flash. When I want to install version for Ubuntu, I get internal error in `/usr/bin/apturl-gtk` with message:

`apturl-gtk crashed with AttributeError in doEnableChannel(): module 'apt_pkg' has no attribute 'Config'`

I also tried to install it manually in Opera Web Browser using this tutorial http://www.opera.com/docs/linux/plugins/install/#flash but this method also failed. Any help?

Comment: Do you have `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so` file?

Comment: I haven't got. I created that folder and move that file to that directory. After that I rebooted Ubuntu. Still not working :(

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

Comment: Thanks, it's working. You can add this message as answer and I will mark this ;)

Comment: This is not really a duplicate as this question is specificially about Opera.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There're multiple conflicting packages, e.g. `flashplayer-mozilla`, `flashplugin-installer`, `adobe-flashplugin`…

The specific one you need for Opera browser is `adobe-flashplugin`, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Update per comments: if you get a `has no installation candidate` error, run `software-properties-gtk`, and set all checkboxes on the *Ubuntu Software* tab. Next update packages list with, e.g., `sudo apt-get update`, and try installing again.

Comment: sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate

Comment: @Jeremy run `software-properties-gtk`, and set all checkboxes on the «Ubuntu Software» tab. Then update packages list with, e.g., `sudo apt-get update`, and try installing again.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Could you please add your comment to your answer to make it more helpful? Notify me if you want an up-vote on the result.

Answer (score 4):

That help page is seriously outdated: “This document was last updated for Opera 11.00” while the current version is 41 and Opera completely switched the rendering engine to Blink (the same as in Chromium/Chrome) in the mean time.

If you look at the packages recommended by the `opera-stable` package, you'll find an entry for `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. This package will install the PPAPI Flash Player plug-in included with Google Chrome which will work with Opera too (otherwise they wouldn't suggest it).

Furthermore, the more recent releases of the `adobe-flashplugin` include the same PPAPI Flash Player without the detour through Google Chrome. You can install it as in [How to install Flash player on Ubuntu?](/q/341428/175814). Use [karel’s answer](/a/990925/175814) if you're unsure since that's the recommended way to install Flash Player in Ubuntu these days, which happens to recommend the same as [Hi-Angel’s answer](/a/763910/175814) here.

Comment: @morpheus: I rolled back your edit. It's superfluous because the installation is explained in the linked question. There's no need to replicate them here and I don't know why it was accepted in review.

Comment: Which answer under the linked question is the good one for Opera?

Comment: @cipricus: See the update to my answer.